# Python - random numbers, higher and lower chances

Tags: python, random, raspberry-pi, integer

i am creating a slot machine with python and now I have the numbers 1-12, choosen randomly by "randint", the problem is now that some of the numbers (3,8,12) trigger an extremly high winning and now I want to add a "higher chance" for the rest of the numbers and for these winning numbers a lower chance. How do I realize this?

Regards,
Simon

Comment: Spoken like a true slot machine designer ;)

Comment: How do you want to realize it? It is up to you as the designer to pick the probabilities. Once you decide on the probabilities, it is easy to pick numbers according to those probabilities (just google "Python random numbers nonuniform probabilities")

Comment: It looks like you are just getting started. Consider posting some code for feedback next time, if you have specific questions.